# How do I go about determining how to wire a breaker box in a cargo trailer

Tags: circuit-breaker

I'm about to wire a cargo trailer with construction equipment, table saw, miter saw, air compressor, drill press, and a few other small tools. Only one tool and lights will used at one time.

So here are my questions. If I plug the trailer into a house with a 110 volt 20 amp circuit, then does it really matter what amp breaker box I use in the trailer? I figure I'm already at the 20 amp rating by doing this.

Otherwise, how do I calculate the breaker panel box that I should buy. I guess I'm asking how should I go about this project at the breaker box?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit -- is the goal to have all of the machines plugged in to their own receptacles, but only one switched on at a time?   I'd investigate the equipment used for RVs.

Answer (score 2):

If all you are planning to do is plug it into a standard 120V receptacle then you don't need a breaker box in the trailer at all. The plug and cord are your means of disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

You could just run your cord (use heavy-duty outdoor wire, 12/3 SJO or bigger) to a junction box inside the trailer, then run EMT or flex metallic conduit on the walls to several receptacles. Like @SpeedyPetey says, no breaker box.
If you want to stay plugged in at the source but kill power to the trailer you could use a small disconnect panel with an integral switch as your junction box.
Remember, wire size should match breaker size. And don't make your extension cord too long or you risk voltage drop, bad for electric motors!